# How can I create an Azure policy that validates Resource Group Names

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to create an Azure policy which I can assign at the subscription level, and control the naming of the resource groups in the subscription.

Policies need to target a resource type or otherwise limit their application, else they apply globally to all resources.

What resource type (or other method) can I use to limit my validation to the **resource group** name only?

Here is what I am trying:

```
$definition = New-AzureRmPolicyDefinition -Name resourceGroupNamePatterns 
   -Description "Restrict resource group names to allowed prefixes only" -Policy '{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "name",
              "like": "Pattern1-*"
            }
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "name",
              "like": "Pattern2-*"
            }
          },
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups"
          }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
    }
}'
```

Comment: did u get answer for this?

Comment: I never tried it, but the answer from @heren in this thread appears to show that the policy I tried originally would work given a policy mode of All (see the accepted answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815452/139200 on this question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this question is still relevant, but at the time of posting Azure Policy did not support evaluation on resource groups.

The policy definition provided in the question is correct.

Please try updating your powershell version, and updating the policy definition. It will default to `mode: all` which in turn will enable policy evaluation on resource groups.

Documentation about Policy mode: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-policy/policy-definition

**Mode**

The mode determines which resource types will be evaluated for a policy. The supported modes are:

- **all**: evaluate resource groups and all resource types
- **indexed**: only evaluate resource types that support tags and location

We recommend that you set mode to all. All policy definitions created through the portal use the all mode. If you use PowerShell or Azure CLI, you need to specify the mode parameter and set it to all.

Comment: Thanks, will try that and report back

Comment: np. Let me know if anything goes wrong and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

The resource groups are `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups` type. You can kinda infer that from the resource provider operations:

```
Get-AzureRmProviderOperation 'Microsoft.Resources/*'
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this and let you know if that type works in the policy to target resource groups. My google-fu wasn't up to discovering this particular nugget of information ;-)

Comment: I tried setting up a policy with that as the resource type. It applied to the subscription OK but did not have any effect (could still create RGs with different names)

Comment: I'm not sure its possible to affect resource groups, tbh. I've tried various combinations and the policy works, but not for resourcegroups. at least in my experiments

Comment: Yep I think the same thing. I have mentioned it to our MS rep, if they come back with a way I will update it here as an answer.